# Is there a library that can stream FLV from an IIS server to an ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, flv

Is there a library that can be used to stream FLV from IIS server and play it in ASP.NET page using C#?

Comment: By "streaming" do you mean actual streaming (versus progressive)?

Comment: The flv file will be located in iis media server and I want to play it in my asp.net page from the server.

Comment: @ Shiv Kumar yes I meant actual streaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at
http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/kfra/archive/2006/10/04/50003.aspx

Be aware that a lot of sites say "streaming" but what they're really doing is  Pseudo Streaming. That is it is actually progressive with the ability to "skip ahead".

What are your reasons for wanting to use streaming?
What are your reasons for choosing flv instead of say H.264 (.mp4)?

I work at http://exposureroom.com and we use Pseudo Streaming with our Html 5 player. If you use the latest versions of browsers you can try out the test page
http://exposureroom.com/html5/

you won't be using IIS Media server by the way. You'll be use IIS and streaming the flv via your ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the flv file in your website folder it should have no problem streaming. If you want to embed it I suggest using [JW flv player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/). You can embed it using good old html in visual studio. You don't need to use c# unless you want to specify the flv file location dynamically or something of other dynamic nature.

Comment: The flv file will be located in iis media server and I want to play it in my asp.net page from the server.